# How do I count the occurrences of a byte in NSData on an iphone?

Tags: ios, nsdata

I'm new to iOS and Objective C and I'm having trouble figuring out how to use NSData correctly.

I want to count the number of new lines in my data.

```
// filedata is pulled from a URL asyn

NSInteger knt = 0;
NSInteger len = filedata.length;
const char *pointer = [filedata bytes];

for (NSInteger spot = 0; spot < len; spot++) {
    if (pointer[spot] == 10) { // 10 is new line
        knt++;
    }
}
```

The count is off, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It was off by 7 with one test file and 12 with another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for carriage returns as well (ascii 13 http://www.asciitable.com/).

Make sure the newlines are TRULY newlines (ascii 10).  You can try this by opening up your data in a hex editor.  Hex editors generally will show you text in a right pane, bytes in a middle pain, and addresses of the bytes in a left pane.

If this doesn't resolve your question, please consider posting sample data.

Comment: I changed it to 13 (CR's) and it gave me the right count.  Very strange as I didn't think there would be a difference.  I guess that code is ok then, thanks Sam!

Comment: I've been bitten more than once by stuff like that (carriage returns vs newlines).  Just glad I could help!